# Bernoulli's inequality case when equal

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We have Bernoulli's inequality. For all $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $a \ge -1$ and all $n \in \mathbb N$ the following inequality holds: $(1 + a)^{n} \ge 1 + na$. Verify that both sides are equal if and only if $a=0$ or $n=1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Also relevant, what level of course is this in? (As a hint, what kind of technique is useful for proving something true for natural numbers?)

Comment: This is from an introductory course on mathematical analysis. I get that induction might be useful here and am able to prove the general inequality by induction. I would be able to prove the equality for both $a=0$ and $n=1$. The problem is, how do I know this is the only case?

Comment: For $a\neq0$ and $n>1$, use induction to prove the strict inequality $(1+a)^n>1+na$.

Answer (score 1):

We shall prove in the first part that if $a = 0$ or $n = 1$, then both sides are equal, and in the second part, we shall prove that if $n \neq 1$ and $a  \neq 0$, then equality doesn't hold.

**First Part**

If $a = 0$, then $(1+a)^n = 1^n = 1$, and $1 + na = 1+0\cdot n = 1$, hence $(1+a)^n = 1 + na$.

If $n = 1$, then $(1+a)^n = (1+a)^1 = 1+a$, and $1 + na = 1 + 1a = 1 + a$, therefore, we again get that $(1+a)^n = 1 + na$.

**Second Part**

We'll prove by induction that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 2$, and every $a > -1$, $a \neq 0$, we have $(1+a)^n > 1 + na$.

For $n = 2$, we get $(1 + a)^n = (1+a)^2 = 1 + 2a + a^2 > 1 +2a = 1 +na$ (since $a \neq 0$).

Suppose the inequality holds for some $n = k \geq 2$, then
\begin{align*}
(1+a)^k & > 1 + ka \\
(1+a)^{k+1} & > (1+a)\cdot(1 + ka)\\
(1+a)^{k+1} & > 1 + ka + a + ka^2\\
(1+a)^{k+1} & > 1 + a(k+1) + ka^2> 1 + (k+1)a\\
(1+a)^{k+1} & > 1 + (k+1)a
\end{align*}
Thus, the proof is complete.